# TcpClient.Connect says "A connection attempt failed because the connected party..."

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, tcpclient

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .NET 3.5 application running on Windows XP SP3 x86. In my application, I have an event handler `OnSendTask` that can be called by multiple threads simultaneously. It opens a TCP connection to a remote host and sends/receives data.

For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// prevent us from exceeding the maximum number of half-open TCP 
/// connections in Windows XP.
/// </summary>
private System.Threading.Semaphore tcp_connection_lock_ = 
    new System.Threading.Semaphore(10, 10);

public event EventHandler<SendTaskEventArgs> SendTask;

private void OnSendTask(object sender, SendTaskEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        tcp_connection_lock_.WaitOne();
        using (TcpClient recipient = new TcpClient())
        {
            // error here!
            recipient.Connect(args.IPAddress, args.Port);
            using (NetworkStream stream = recipient.GetStream())
            {
                // read/write data
            }
    }
    catch
    {
        // write exceptions to the logfile
    }
    finally
    {
        tcp_connection_lock_.Release();
    }
}

void SendTasks(int tasks_to_send)
{
    using (ManualResetEvent done_event = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        int countdown = tasks_to_send;
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks_to_send; ++i)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                SendTaskEventArgs args = new SendTaskEventArgs(/*...*/);

                EventHandler<SendTaskEventArgs> evt = SendTask;
                if (evt != null)
                    evt(this, e);

                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref countdown) == 0)
                    done_event.Set();
            }, i);
        }
        done_event.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I occasionally see this error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.0.16:59596
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
```

Some points of information:

- If I send a task to 40 remotes, I will see this response from around 6.
- A Wireshark trace shows no attempt to even initiate a TCP connection from the PC to the remote.
- I can ping the remote from the PC and get consistent good responses.
- The remotes are all on the same switch and subnet as the PC running this application. There is no fancy networking in the way.

Can anybody suggest what may be causing this error or how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: If you send a task to 1 remote, does it always succeed? The error message makes it look like the remote party is causing the problem.

Comment: I have never seen it fail to send to 1 remote. I agree about the way the error message sounds, but point 2 suggests the PC isn't even attempting to make the connection.

Comment: You might need to provide more code.  How is OnSendTask being called?  Where are you calling tcp_connection_lock_.Release()?

Comment: @EricDahlvang - oops. see update. 
OnSendTask is being called through an event delegate which may be invoked by many threads simultaneously. If 40 remotes are receiving the task 40 simultaneous threads may hit that event. But only 10 may hit the `TcpClient.Connect` call due to the semaphore.

Comment: Do you still get this error if you run the application on a machine other than the Windows XP SP3 x86?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure of all of the details behind the max half-open TCP connections but, I believe it is NOT specific to application connections, but rather system wide.  Are you sure that when this error occurs there are no other applications on the system that are creating TCP connections?

I'd setup a retry whenever an error occurs.  Something like:

```
private const int MaxRetries = 10;
private void OnSendTask(object sender, SendTaskEventArgs args)
{
    bool retry = false;
    try
    {
        tcp_connection_lock_.WaitOne();
        using (TcpClient recipient = new TcpClient())
        {
            // error here!
            recipient.Connect(args.IPAddress, args.Port);
            using (NetworkStream stream = recipient.GetStream())
            {
                // read/write data
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        if(args.RetryCount < MaxRetries)
        {
            retry = true;
            args.RetryCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            // write exceptions to the logfile
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        tcp_connection_lock_.Release();
    }

    if(retry)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        OnSendTask(sender, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done some more analysis and as it turns out, the issue was that the remotes were not always responding to the ARP request sent before the TCP SYN. (buggy TCP stack?) 
Your solution effectively works around the issue because we're now sending more ARP requests, so you get the answer point. :)